# Create Multiple Choice InfoPath 2010 Form

Tags: infopath

I have a multiple choice InfoPath 2010 form that I would like the abilty to fill out and submit to a Sharepoint document library. I know how to connect the form to SharePoint, but am not sure to which control to use in setting up the mulitple choice radio buttons and also how or if possible to grade the form once submitted.

Below I have added a picture of how I would like it to look, but need the functionality for it to work. Any info would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, InfoPath will represent a choice field as a drop-down. To show it as a radio button form, you will need to manipulate it in InfoPath.

Select the control on the canvas and then change the control to an option button
[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

Copy and paste the one option button as many times as required.

Now manually type the option values next to each button.

[image]

Next, select each option button in turn and set its Properties. In the field "Value when selected" enter the value that option represents.

[image]

Publish the form and test.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your list/document library that will hold the results create a field for each answer that is of type "Choice". Fill the the possible answers each on its own line.

On your InfoPath Form you can display that field as a series of Radio buttons all bound to the one field. When the user submits the form it will add a new row in the library and there will be a field for each answer with the value that they selected. This should allow for easy grading, either manually or automatically.

see [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-list-HA010099248.aspx#BM2) for how to create a list and add your fields to it.
see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg180738%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for how to customize the form for the list.

Comment: I understand at a high level of what you are saying, but do you know of a step by step article that can help? Thanks Ryan!

Comment: see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-list-HA010099248.aspx#BM2 for creating a custom list and fields. Then create an InfoPath form based on the new list.

Comment: I updated the answer with some articles that should help get you started. Also don't forget to mark the answer as accepted using the check button, if it solved your problem.