# Field Labels in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

Seems like a really simple question but I can't find anything about how to add labels to InfoPath fields?

I just want a text label beside a checkbox for example.

I know I can just type the text in beside the checkbox, but I would prefer to have an assigned label.

Surely this functionality exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you are forced to manually type the value next to the checkbox. However, you can then select the check box / radio button, and modify the properties of the input, and select the **value when selected**. One of the reasons this behaves this way, is that this allows you to create multiple views, which could be "translated" into multiple languages, without hard-coding the value that pairs with the input.

SharePoint Stack Exchange: [Example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/67855/9345)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated value for this (expression box in InfoPath 2007). A calculated value can be a string value or it can be a formula comprised functions and / or fields.

For a dynamic label, you could bind the calculated value to a field in an XML data source (like the main data source in your form, or a secondary XML you add for this purpose), and use form logic to set the value.